# Display 3D wireframe over 2D texture on Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, texture

I have a .obj file with a 3D object and a .tga one with the texture. If I open the .obj in Photoshop and load the .tga as diffuse texture, everything looks fine, but I am having some hard time editing the texture, Specially finding the edge borders.

What I would like to have is, the lines I can see when choosing the "Wireframe" preset on the 3D scene, I would like to see them as a plain 2D over the .tga texture, so I would know where each edge of the 3D object is corresponding to the texture.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Open the 3D file, then open the texture by either clicking on it in the Layers panel or selecting the material in the 3D panel, then in the (Material) properties, click on the icon next to Diffuse and select Edit Texture. The properties panel should now show the painting options, in which You can check UV Overlay to show the vertices (edges) and change the color and opacity.

Bonus: If you open the (Photoshop 3D) file (and material texture) and have the two images side-by-side, when you move the paintbrush over the model, crosshairs will show up on the texture—the same works for painting on the texture (showing crosshairs on the model).